# float object is not callable even I didn't use function name

Tags: python

```
import math
i=0
arm_pop=float(0)
for i in range(1,16):
    arm_pop=round(1000000*math.e(3*i)/(10000+100(math.e((3*i)-1))))
    print(arm_pop)
```

---

```
<>:5: SyntaxWarning: 'int' object is not callable; perhaps you missed a comma?
<>:5: SyntaxWarning: 'int' object is not callable; perhaps you missed a comma?
C:\Users\pasto\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_22396/4049563446.py:5: SyntaxWarning: 'int' object is not callable; perhaps you missed a comma?
  arm_pop=round(1000000*math.e(3*i)/(10000+100(math.e((3*i)-1))))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_22396/4049563446.py in <module>
      3 arm_pop=float(0)
      4 for i in range(1,16):
----> 5     arm_pop=round(1000000*math.e(3*i)/(10000+100(math.e((3*i)-1))))
      6     print(arm_pop)
      7 

TypeError: 'float' object is not callable
```

---

I didn't use function names, but the error comes out. How do I solve this error?

Comment: You can't use mathematical notation. For example, it's not `100a` but `100*a`

Comment: [`math.e`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.e) is the number, you probably want [`math.exp()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.exp)

Comment: the problem is in math.e => math.exp(x) it will work

Comment: I think you also need a "*" after the 100

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to add an operator after `math.e`, therefore, Python is interpreting it as a function call.

```
1000000*math.e(3*i)
```

Your code should be something like

```
1000000*math.e<your operator>(3*i) 
# concretely something like
1000000*math.e/(3*i)
```

Or perhaps your were looking for an exponential function, with would be something like `math.exp(value)`, which raises `e` to the given power(`value` parameter), as mentioned in the direct comments.

**EDIT**

You forgot several operators, please note that Python does not interpret `100x` as `100*x` - every mathematical operation must be written explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Here you've missed * sign
math.e((3*i)

Answer (score 0):

`math.e` is a float, not a function. Remember python isn't exactly written as math. you should do this:

```
import math
i=0
arm_pop=float(0)
for i in range(1,16):
    print(math.e)
    arm_pop=round(1000000*math.e*(3*i)/(10000+100*(math.e*((3*i)-1))))
    print(arm_pop)
```

Comment: That still won't run, `100(math.e[...]` raises a TypeError

Comment: Works for me though

Comment: Try it again I've edited it

Comment: Yes, works now. Certainly didn't work before ;)

Comment: Do you understand why your old code doesn't work?

Comment: Remember syntax error is an error something to do with python language style not the logic of your code.

Comment: I'm not the person that asked the question and I do know why it didn't work